# Counter Function in Python - Within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sudoku

I currently have the following 9x9 array:

```
m = np.zeros((9,9)) #9x9 grid of all zeros 
vals = np.arange(1,10) #set of values from 1 to 9 aranged randomly
for i in range(0,9):
    m[i,:] = np.random.choice(vals,size=9,replace=False) #randomly choses a set of 9 values for the row
print(m.astype(int)) #prints as integers
```

Using this I have created a function called nonet_1:

```
def nonet_1():
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            print(m[i,j])
nonet_1()
```

I am wanting to use a similar idea, as below, using Counter function.

```
[r - 1 for r in Counter((m[:,i])).values()] #this line of code produces the scores based on n.o repeats in each column
```

The overall aim to count the number of duplications within this 3x3 grid in the nonet_1 function. Is there a simple way I can bring these together?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def nonet_1():
    number_of_times_any_value_duplicated = sum([i for i in Counter(m[:3,:3].flatten()).values() if i > 1])
    print (number_of_times_any_value_duplicated)
```